# WebdriverIO automation testing when JavaScript is disabled

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, browser-automation, wdio-v4

Is there a way in WebdriverIO framework to launch the browser with JavaScript disabled?

I want to automate a scenario with JavaScript being disabled. But, when I manually disable the JavaScript in Chrome, or Firefox and run the WDIO scripts, the browser always opens with JavaScript enabled.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @iamdanchiv The solution provided by you worked. The best way. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**Not anymore.** (but you have a workaround below)

This used to be easily achieved using the [**chromium switches**](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). But considering all driver implementations (`chromedriver`, `geckodriver`, etc.) now **require JavaScript** to drive your spawned browser instance, it's no longer possible.

It was achieved via `chromeOptions` arguments/switches:

```
capabilities: [{

        maxInstances: 2,

        browserName: config[env].browser,
        chromeOptions: {

            args: ['--disable-javascript',
                   '--disable-javascript-harmony-shipping'
            ]
        }
    }]
```

**!!! LATER EDIT:** You can achieve this by loading a custom profile.

1. Start your WebdriverIO test case, but add a `browser.debug()` after you load your page;
2. In the address bar, type **chrome://settings/content** and in the modal, check the **Do not allow any site to run JavaScript**. Click **Done**. Now go to a random page and notice JavaScript has been blocked on it: [image]
3. Now we have to save this **custom profile** and load it each time you start a WebdriverIO test case. Type **chrome://version** in your address bar. Notice the **Profile Path** value. Copy the content of the folder (e.g.: For `C:\Users\<yourUserName>\Desktop\scoped_dir18256_17319\Default`, copy the **scoped_dir18256_17319** folder on your Desktop). This folder contains all the actions (search history, extensions installed, accounts saved... in our case, JavaScript disabled option) on **THIS** current instance.
4. Now all we need to do, is add the path to that folder in your `wdio.config.js` file as a `chromeOptions` argument:

   ```
   chromeOptions: {
       //extensions: ['./browserPlugins/Avira-SafeSearch-Plus_v1.5.1.crx'],
       args: [ '--user-data-dir=/Users/<yourUserName>/Desktop/scoped_dir18256_17319'
       ]
   }
   ```

Now all you have to do is run your test cases with this custom profile and JavaScript will be blocked on all websites. Hope this is the behavior you are looking for as there is no other way to achieve this behavior.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @iamdanchiv for this help. It really worked out for me. I tried all others way and it never worked out. The approach you said was perfect.